# VHDL Is there a cleaner way to set specific bit, given the bit number?

Tags: vhdl

Given a bit number, I am trying to set that bit in a std_logic_vector.  This is for toggling various clock outputs one at a time.

First of all, I've completely given up on sll, or SHIFT_LEFT which seems to be the obvious way to do it, but which totally doesn't work at all.

```
variable v_cmd_clk_1: std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);

...

--- set bit number "s_proc_chan", plus 4, in v_cmd_clk_1
v_cmd_clk_1 := "0000" & "0000" & "0000";
v_cmd_clk_1( to_integer ( unsigned(s_proc_chan(2 downto 0))) + 4  ) := '1';

...
-- And then later on in the process assign it to an actual signal
cmd_clk <= v_cmd_clk_0;
```

Is there a better or cleaner syntax for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are constantly dealing with unsightly type conversions then it is time to evaluate if you are using the right types for your signals. `s_proc_chan` may be better suited as an `unsigned` or an integer record element instead of a slice of a larger vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three suggestions for you. First one uses aggregates:

```
v_cmd_clk_1 <= (to_integer(unsigned(s_proc_chan(2 downto 0)))+4) => '1', others => '0');
```

Second one uses integer to *unsigned* conversion:

```
v_cmd_clk_1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2**(to_integer(unsigned(s_proc_chan(2 downto 0)))+4)); -- No guarantee on parentheses matching
```

Third one, using `shift_left`:

```
v_cmd_clk_1 <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(resize(unsigned'("1"), v_cmd_clk_1'length), to_integer(unsigned(s_proc_chan(2 downto 0)))+4));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will give those alternates a try.

Answer (score 3):

The principle of setting a single bit given by index, as you already done, is fine, and it shows the intention of the code, which is setting a bit given by an index.

It would be possible to eliminate the `+ 4` offset through use of other `std_logic_vector` ranges, but a decent synthesis tool eliminates the offset, so an add operation is not implemented.

Anyhow, as answer to the comment, the `+ 4` can be eliminated if a `std_logic_vector` is addressed directly into 0 to 7, instead of addressing 4 to 11, and the last 4 `'0'`s can just be postpended, like:

```
variable v_cmd_clk_1    : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
variable v_cmd_clk_upper: std_logic_vector( 7 downto 0);
...
v_cmd_clk_upper := (others => '0');
v_cmd_clk_upper(to_integer(unsigned(s_proc_chan(2 downto 0)))) := '1';
v_cmd_clk_1 := v_cmd_clk_upper & "0000";
```

The aggregate suggested by Jonathan Drolet looks nice, but for example Altera Quartus II won't allow this for synthesis, since it requires constant choice values in aggregates.  Using `shift` or `2**` will synthesize.

Note that initial clearing is more general with:

```
v_cmd_clk_1 := (others => '0');
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would you eliminate the +4?

Comment: @NXT: Please see update in answer for how to eliminate the `+4`.